# SOLR - search results without any default sort

Tags: sorting, solr, default

I'm searching with the following query:
/select?q=*:*&fq=fld:dddd OR fld:aaaa OR fld:bbbb
where, the field fld is a String type and uniqueKey.

I'm getting results as:

```
<doc>
   <str name="fld">aaaa</str>
</doc>
<doc>
   <str name="fld">bbbb</str>
</doc>
<doc>
   <str name="fld">dddd</str>
</doc>
```

Looks like the results But I want the results to be "un-sorted"... meaning, I want the results to be in the order in which I have given in the fq condition. That is, I want the results as follows:

```
<doc>
   <str name="fld">dddd</str>
</doc>
<doc>
   <str name="fld">aaaa</str>
</doc>
<doc>
   <str name="fld">bbbb</str>
</doc>
```

How do we do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you add `score` to your `fl` then you will see that all of them has  the same score value, so it is sorted on `fld`  -thats why you see aaaa bbbb dddd-

you can change scoring or give `boost` on query time, depending on your `fl` order to get a similar thing but other than those I dont think it is possible to have it without writing a plugin or hacking solr source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a RandomSortField to your schema.  Then sort the results randomly.  See:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html

EDIT: After re-reading the post, I realize that's not what you're looking for.  You might try sorting using a function:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery